# Value of $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{a^h-1}{h}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm given a question by my friend. State the value of $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{a^h-1}{h}$ for $a=2$.

Then I've used l'Hopital's rule to solve it and I got the answer of $\ln 2$.

But my friend said need to be solved by first principles method. I wonder how. Can anyone show me? Thanks.

Comment: use difference of powers to expand the numerator

Comment: Is that related to derivatives first principle

Comment: Have a look at: [How to prove that $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{a^h - 1}{h} = \ln a$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77348/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-h-to-0-fracah-1h-ln-a).
These two questions are about derivatives, but they are basically just a reformulation of the same question: 
[Proof of the fact that $\ln(a) = f '(0)$ for $f(x) = a^x$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/951730/proof-of-the-fact-that-lna-f-0-for-fx-ax) and
[Show that $d/dx (a^x) = a^x\ln a$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398826/show-that-d-dx-ax-ax-ln-a)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1828962/is-it-valid-to-write-1-lim-x-rightarrow-0-fracex-1x-frac-lim-x

Answer (score 5):

**Hints**

1. Use the definition of the derivative of $f(x)=a^x$ at $x=0$ to construct your limit.
2. Next, use the differentiation formula $(a^x)'=a^x \ln a$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{a^h-1}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{\ln a^h}-1}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{h\ln a}-1}{h \ln(a)} \ln(a)\\
=\ln(a)\lim_{s\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{s}-1}{s}$$

Now identify the last limit as the definition of the derivative of $e^x$ at $x=0$.